# User control page_load event invoked before the Button click event of the aspx page

Tags: c#

I want to assign property value on button click in aspx page and want to pass the value to the usercontrol and than bind data according to the Property value.
But the problem is before button click event is fired the page_load of user control is invoved ? is the any way to call the page_load of user control again on button click or is there anyother alternative to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing Page_Load from a UserControl makes the control very dependant on the page life cycle and thus not very flexible. A better way would be to add a public method to the control that you call from the button OnClick event. That method would then perform the data binding.

Kinda like this:

```
//MyPage.aspx
void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MyUserControl.DataBind(MyTextBox.Text);
}

//MyUserControl.ascx
public void DataBind(string value)
{
UpdateView(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kludgy, but if you have to you can always call the Page_load event manually after the button fires.

A better approach would be: depending on what code needs to fire after the button_click event, you can move it to another event handler, like the OnPreRender method.